# Adding item to Available Reports in Trac (via Plugin)

Tags: plugins, trac

Is it possible to add a Ticket Report to the Available Reports via a plugin, so that after installing the plugin it becomes automatically available? Or would one have to manually save a custom query with the intended columns and filters?

If it is possible to do this via python code, what is the Trac interface to be implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert the reports through an implementation of [IEnvironmentSetupParticipant](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracDev/PluginDevelopment/ExtensionPoints/trac.env.IEnvironmentSetupParticipant). Example usage in [env.py](http://trac.edgewall.org/browser/tags/trac-1.0.9/trac/env.py#L781). In `env.py` the reports are inserted in `environment_created`. You'll want to insert reports in `upgrade_environment`. Example code for inserting the report can be found in [report.py](http://trac.edgewall.org/browser/tags/trac-1.0.9/trac/ticket/report.py?marks=222-226#L213). `needs_upgrade` determines whether `upgrade_environment` is called on Environment startup so you'll need to provide the logic that determines whether your reports are already present, returning `False` if they are present and `True` if they are not. If `True` is returned, then `upgrade_environment` will get called (for your case `environment_created` can just be `pass`, or it can directly call `upgrade_environment`, the latter being a minor optimization discussed in [#8172](http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/8172#comment:43)). See the [Database Schema](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracDev/DatabaseSchema#DatabaseSchemaTrac0.12) for information on the `report` table.

In Trac 1.2 (not yet released) we've tried to make it easier to work with the database by adding methods to the [DatabaseManager class](http://trac.edgewall.org/browser/tags/trac-1.0.9/trac/db/api.py#L224). [DatabaseManager for Trac 1.1.6](http://trac.edgewall.org/browser/tags/trac-1.1.6/trac/db/api.py#L303) includes methods `set_database_version` and `get_database_version`. This is useful for reducing the amount of code needed in `IEnvironmentSetupParticipant.needs_upgrade` when checking whether the database tables need to be upgraded (even simpler would be to just call [DatabaseManager.needs_upgrade](http://trac.edgewall.org/browser/tags/trac-1.1.6/trac/db/api.py#L454)). There's also an `insert_into_tables` method that you could use to insert reports.

That said, I'm not sure you need to put an entry for your plugin in the `system` table using `set_database_version`. You can probably just query the `report` table and check if your report is present, use that check to return a boolean from `IEnvironmentSetupParticipant.needs_upgrade`, which will determine whether `IEnvironmentSetupParticipant.upgrade_environment` gets called. If you are developing for Trac 1.0.x, you can copy code from the DatabaseManager class in Trac 1.1.6. Another approach can be seen with [CodeReviewerPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/CodeReviewerPlugin), for which I made a [compat.py](https://trac-hacks.org/browser/codereviewerplugin/1.0/coderev/compat.py) module that adds the methods I needed. The advantage of the `compat.py` approach is that the methods can be copied from the `DatabaseManager` class without polluting the main modules of your codebase. In the future when your plugin drops support for Trac < 1.2 you can just delete the `compat.py` module and modify the imports in your plugin code, but not have to change any of your primary plugin logic.